# Need to create hyperlinks of each imported sheet with name of original Excel file where imported sheets came from via VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, import, hyperlink, spreadsheet

Created a macro that imports sheets from different files. Want to create hyperlinks in separate sheet of targeted workbook but I want to use the same name of the Excel file where the original import sheets came from, instead  of creating hyperlinks of title of the imported sheets.

```
Sub ImportSheetsFromFolder()
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim selectedFile As Variant
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim sheetName As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim x As Integer
    
    ' Prompt user to select folder
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Select Folder Containing Excel Files"
        If .Show = -1 Then
            folderPath = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            MsgBox "No folder selected. Exiting."
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    
    ' Set target workbook (current workbook)
    Set targetWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Prompt user for sheet name to import
    sheetName = InputBox("Enter the name of the sheet to import:", "Sheet Name")
    If sheetName = "" Then
        MsgBox "No sheet name provided. Exiting."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Loop through each file in the selected folder
    selectedFile = Dir(folderPath & "\*.xlsx")
    Do While selectedFile <> ""
        ' Open source workbook
        Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(folderPath & "\" & selectedFile)
        
        ' Check if the sheet exists in the source workbook
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = sourceWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        ' If the sheet exists, import it into the target workbook
       
          If Not ws Is Nothing Then
            ws.Copy After:=targetWorkbook.Sheets(targetWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
         
        End If

        
        ' Close the source workbook without saving changes
        sourceWorkbook.Close False
        
        ' Move to the next file
        selectedFile = Dir
    Loop
    
    MsgBox "Import complete."
    
     'Create hyperlink for each sheet that was imported into seperate sheet in target WB
  Worksheets("Hyperlink").Select
  Range("A1").Select
  
  For Each ws In targetWorkbook.Worksheets
  ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ActiveCell, Address:="", SubAddress:="sourceWorkbook" & ws.Name & "!A1" & "", ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:=ws.Name
  ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
  Next ws
   
     End Sub
     
 Tried using sourcebook as a target name for hyperlink but not working
```

Comment: You need to create the link immediately after `ws.Copy` while you have the source file name in `sourceWorkbook.Name`, or you need to track the source workbook for each copied sheet as you run through the Dir() loop.